# Customizing the listview to start from middle

Tags: android, listview

I would like to develop something as shown in the image:

[image: number]

And when I click on the number it should display a list view as shown in the second image.

[image: list]

Now how can I get the `ListView` from somewhere in the middle. Actual contents of list start from 58 to say 98. It may not be 72 always.

Comment: what do you mean by actual contents of list start from 58 to say 98?

Comment: list displays numbers from 58 to 98

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setSelection(position)` to jump to index/position where that particular number/item is present ... you will have to create a formula to calculate the index/position  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: it would be easier if you change the Background color of item via STATElistDrawable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html  ... but if you really want to change text color of textview try this http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2010/12/28/Android%3A-Change-ListView-Row-TextView-Color-When-Checked